# How to mimize number of url definitions in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-urls

In Django you create a URL for a link/end point in your website. My question is if you are creating something with a lot of links say a blog app you can literally have hundreds or thousands of url definitions in your urls.py. Assuming the links have no parameters that is the url does not capture input then such Django app will need to device a way to utilize a database to minimize url definition. Does anybody can think of a more efficient solution?

Comment: Well, your assumption doesn't seem valid. Why wouldn't you capture a slug value in the URL to determine what content to show?

Comment: @Daniel are you talking about like (r'^myapp/(?P<mylink>/$', views.showpage), then just check with swictch/if statement or via ORM?

Comment: Well yes, but I don't know what an if statement would be doing there (and Python doesn't have switch).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

URLs in Django can have parameters which can be substituted to generate a whole lot of URLs.

Lets say your `Blog` model is something like

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    title=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    content=models.TextField()
```

Then, you can create a URL for every blog by defining your URL as

```
url("^blog/([0-9]+)/$, views.blog_details)
```

The `([0-9]+` part tells Django to look for a number as an argument, which would be a URL like `/blogs/1234/` for example

The corresponding view function would take the blog id as an argument

```
def blog_details(blog_id):
    blog=get_object_or_404(Blog, pk=blog_id)
    # generate view of this blog from template
```

You can do a whole lot with URL parameters, more info at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/urls/

Comment: You may want to use: get_object_or_404()   https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404